# Extended class gets only initial value of parent's variable

Tags: php, class, parent

```
class MyAppClass {

    protected $_config = array();

    protected $_template = '';

    public function init( ){

       require_once('core_config.php'); // Inside is $_SC_config with an array of values

       $this->_config = $_SC_config;

       $this->_template = new template;

       echo $this->_template->echo_base();

    }

}

class template extends MyAppClass{

    public function echo_base() {

       var_dump($this->_config); // returns empty array

    }

}

$myApp = new MyAppClass;
$myApp->init();
```

What's wrong with code above so

> var_dump($this->_config)

in template class returns empty array after init function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And why there should be value?

Comment: You're creating a new template instance inside of `init`, which itself hasn't been initialised. Your class hierarchy might need some thought.

Comment: This is simply not how inheritance works.

Comment: Use a __construct() function Also you are supposed to instantiate the child class not parent

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't get object programming yet. In `MyAppClass::init` method you create new object of `template` class which extends your `MyAppClass` class. I have no idea what do you want to acheve but I will show you snippet which works.

```
<?php
class MyAppClass {

    protected $_config = array();

    protected $_template = '';

    protected function init( ){

       //require_once('core_config.php'); // Inside is $_SC_config with an array of values

       $this->_config = 'foo';

    }

}

class template extends MyAppClass{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->init();
    }

    public function echo_base() {

       var_dump($this->_config); // returns empty array

    }

}

$myApp = new template;
$myApp->echo_base();
```

Comment: kmike, you're right, I just started rewriting my app with oop methods. Thank you for your sample!